# Getting ValueError: math domain error in Python

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I wrote a short Python code to compute the Discrete Fourier Transform of a signal. Here is the code.

```
#import packages
from numpy import *
import math
import cmath

def computedft(x):
#function to calculate the dft of a signal
#Inputs : x(t) time domain signal
#output : K Fourier coff magnitudes

        N=len(x)
        #Caluclate omeag for DFT
        omega=2* math.pi /N
        for k in range(N):
        #outer loop is for each Fourier Coff
                sum=0
                for i in range(N):
                        sum=sum+x[i]*exp(- math.sqrt(-1)*k*omega*i)
                X[k]=sum
        return X
```

Then I went to ipython and gave these commands

```
In [1]: x=[9,6,7,8,9,-4,-8,-1]

In [2]: import computedft

In [3]: computedft.computedft(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

~/Documents/<ipython console> in <module>()

~/Documents/computedft.py in computedft(x)
     16                 sum=0
     17                 for i in range(N):
---> 18                         sum=sum+x[i]*exp(- math.sqrt(-1)*k*omega*i)
     19                 X[k]=sum
     20         return X

ValueError: math domain error
```

I dont understand why I am getting this error. I have included the cmath package, so thus it should be able to multiply complex numbers. But why doesnt it work?

Comment: You could replace "math.sqrt(-1)" with "1j"

Answer (score 2):

use `cmath` instead of `math`:

```
In [123]: math.sqrt(-1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-5234f21f3b4d> in <module>()
----> 1 math.sqrt(-1)

ValueError: math domain error

In [124]: import cmath

In [125]: cmath.sqrt(-1)
Out[125]: 1j
```

Comment: ok, I got it, so if we import cmath package then we dont need to import math package separately, I have another doubt: when I make changes to the code I m using vim editor then I run in ipython `import computedft` and then run the python file, it doesnt get updated and still shows the error before I made the change. If I quit ipython and restart it, then it compiles the new code. Why does this happen?

Comment: once you've imported a package (e.g. `computedft`), it's cached in dictionary `sys.modules`, next time you import it, it's omitted. So you need to restart ipython kernel, or `reload(computedft)` ;)

Comment: You could just use "1j" as it is an (imaginary) literal [imaginary meaning imaginary number]